# ASP.NET how can I get the value of gridview footer rows

Tags: asp.net

```
  if (_myDs.Tables[_orderItemsName].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = _myDs.Tables[_orderItemsName].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
        Response.Write(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
        Response.Write(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
        gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = (temp + Convert.ToInt32((lblClothPrice.Text).ToString())).ToString();
        //gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(lblClothPrice.Text.ToString());
    }`enter code here`
```

Hi I am trying get the value in 3rd cell of footer which is a number that for total price, then add some value on it, but this

```
Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
```

just give me this error "FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." but when I test it in

```
Response.Write(gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
```

its works fine.
by the way it is built fine.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the actual string returned by `gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString()`?

Comment: First I want to thank you for your reply!!

Comment: its a whole number, when I use response.write()...it display the number on the screen

Comment: There maybe hidden whitespace formatting in there.  I've done similar code, and the gridview ended up adding '&nbsp;' to most of the column data.  View the actual emitted html to verify the content in that cell.  If this is the case, remove the whitespace prior to converting to an Int32.

Comment: thank you,I will give it a try, but if it is a white space problem, why the response.write() statement does not give me an error? I just check the html "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>Total</td><td>32</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>" the third cell does not have any space

Comment: Your Response.Write didn't convert the text to an integer, which made me think some non-numeric characters were there.  If you put a break point at the first line of code (the one that gives the exception), what is the value of `gvItems.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString()`?